# Can I create authentication ntlm in SWIFT 2.0?

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, swift2, ntlm

I find nothing updated on this issue. Could anyone help me?. Thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you actually are trying to do as it is not very clear at all.

Comment: Yes of course. I'm working on the next project: access lists sharepoint 2013 Local but this need to authentication ntlm Windows username and password but I lost becauseI cant find updated information about this.